# Can i change the url of an iOS App?

Tags: ios

I develop currently an iOS App which is connected to a web server. The functionality is on the web server the client only visualized for the user. To reach the web server i hardcoded the URL to the web server in xcode.

But when i release the app every user has his own web server and URLs. My idea is to give the user the opportunity to change the url by himself after the app is started. I will show a little window for typing the url.

The problem is that i read that apple doesnt completely allow to change the url in this way. Then reason is, when i change this url the functionality of the app can also be modified.

Is this right ?

Can i solve this in an other way ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few approaches to this problem.

1. If this is a library for use by developers, read the URL from a plist file.
2. Use a standard URL structure and redirect to the proper URL. For example, have the user enter an "account ID" 1234 that calls a URL on your server http://example.com/accounts/1234 which does a 302 redirect to the right URL. You'll need to maintain a mapping of IDs to endpoints in your server/database.
3. Give users a subdomain at your host and setup a CNAME for each account to the user's own server. Again, have the user enter their account ID 1234. Then setup a CNAME on http://a1234.example.com directed at http://usersdomain.com.

I'm sure there are other ways to solve this problem, but these are the first to come to mind.

Comment: Can't see how this will remove Apple's concern.

Comment: I'm sure you're allowed to include different parameters in your URL. I don't think they want to allow the user to hit entirely arbitrary URLs though. In any case, I think these are fair ways around raising their concern in the first place.

Comment: an other way is to use the app preferences and let the user put there the URL to the server. But i dont know that apple allow this